# Where is the documentation of Scikit-Learn 0.14

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ubuntu-14.04

For some reason, Ubuntu 14.04 seems to provide a debian package for a very old scikit-learn (0.14, released in 2010). We need all used libraries to be available as some sort of debian package available on a ppa in order make software deployment easier. So either create a ppa for a pip library (scikit 0.17) or just use the already old but available one (0.14). The problem is that with this old version I get errors when I try using Ransac.

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RANSACRegressor'

I have been looking for the documentation of 0.14 with no success. It might be that there was an API change or that Ransac was not implemented at all in version 0.14. How can I find this documentation?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150408231507/http://scikit-learn.org/0.14/

Comment: may I ask how you found that?

Comment: [waybackmachine](https://archive.org/web/) is awesome

Comment: @Mehdi, from the website you can guess the url that used to be online. Then you check if there's an archived version and voila.

Comment: how the hell can this question attract opinionated answers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation for `scikit-learn´version 0.14 here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/0.14.X/doc

`RANSACRegressor`was introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/c2a2bfe45b16bf6cca9055674b8b68da57af8ead) into `scikit-learn`version 0.15.

Answer (score 0):

14.04 was released 2 years ago (April 2014), so it's no wonder the version is old. Your best bet is to [create your own PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa) and add it to the sources for `apt`.

Comment: still though a 2 years old Ubuntu using a 6 years old... There is probably good reasons why it is the way it is but still kind of annoying.